# Display Api in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to loop through data from an API call in ReactJS but I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined" what am I doing wrong?

```
function TryFetch() {
const [camps, setCamps] = useState([]);



useEffect(() => {
    axios.get(api)
        .then( res => {
            console.log(res)
            setCamps(res.data)
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err);
        })
}, [])

return (

        <div>
            <ul>

                {camps && camps.RECDATA.map(post => (
                    <li key={post.CampsiteID}>{post.CampsiteID}</li>

                ))}
                
                
                
            </ul>   
        </div>

    )
```

}

Comment: Use the Chrome developer tools to debug your code. You should inspect the value of `camps` to see what it contains.

Comment: I think you need to remove the `[]` parameter from the `useEffect()` call.

Comment: Check the output of the console to see how `res` looks like.

Comment: removing the [ ]  worked thanks

Answer (score 1):

At the time react is running the `map` the first time `RECDATA` is not yet defined.

Change your code like this

Replace `{camps && camps.RECDATA.map(post => (` with  `{camps && camps.RECDATA && camps.RECDATA.map(post => (`

Comment: api brings back the data in an object with a property of RECDATA